# SSL Certificate Authentication error in ASP.NET Core MVC application on localhost

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm facing a SSL certificate authentication issue in my ASP.NET Core MVC application when making API requests using `HttpClient` on localhost. The application works perfectly fine when published to the server, but on localhost, I encounter the following error whenever the the API is called:

[image]

I have implemented certificate-based authentication using `HttpClient` to interact with an external API. The strange thing is that this issue only occurs on localhost, while it works perfectly fine after deploying to the server.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Ensured the certificate thumbprint in the code matches the installed certificate on my machine.
2. Verified that the application has read access to the certificate file.
3. Checked that the certificate is installed in the correct store location.

Despite trying these steps, the error persists. I suspect that it might be related to some specific SSL configuration differences between localhost and the server environment, but I'm not sure where to look next.

Here is the code I use to interact with the API:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certificate = store.Certificates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SerialNumber == "5E49F4CC");
store.Close();

handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

string apiResponse = null;
        
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var content = new StringContent(query, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(ApiUrl, content))
    {
        apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that it works fine when I interact with the API via Postman or PowerShell. Is Visual Studio set up differently to interact with certificate authenticated API's?

Could someone please provide some guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this SSL certificate authentication error when running the application on localhost?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The user it's running under cannot access the private key. Add it instead to the user Personal store, for the user that is running the test application.